# Squeak(smalltalk) subSrings ignores empty strings at end of string

Tags: substring, newline, smalltalk, squeak

I'm trying to identify the newlines at the end of a string 
using subStrings.

problem:

```
check := 's
' subStrings: Character cr asString.

Transcript show: check size ; cr.
"prints: 1"
Transcript show: check ; cr.
"prints: #('s')"
```

I would **expect** to have 2 strings as my check string contains a cr character, and subStrings to return #('s''')

while the newlines are present in the check string

```
check := 's
'.
Transcript show: check size ; cr.
"prints: 2"
```

Answer (score 4):

In Squeak, there is `splitBy:`. It is defined in `SequenceableCollection`.
While `subStrings` and `findTokens:` do search for any of a set of delimiters, `splitBy:` consider the delimiters as a whole sequence to be matched for.
Also, such delimiter sequence always split a left and right sub-collection, possibly empty.

Thus you can use:

```
check := 's
' splitBy: String cr.
```

Comment: You are right! I had missed that method! (see the addendum to my answer.)

Answer (score 3):

The method works the way it does, and I think it is consistent with its name because there is nothing inside the `String` after its last character.

In Pharo and other dialects of Smalltalk you have the method `split:', which does what you want in your case:

```
Character cr split: 's
'
```

will answer with `#('s' '')`

You may want to add a (very) simplified version of `#split:` to Squeak on the lines of

```
Character >> split: aString
    | strings |
    aString isEmpty ifTrue: [^Array new].
    strings := aString subStrings: self asString.
    aString last = self ifTrue: [strings := strings copyWith: ''].
    ^strings
```

Note that I've treated the empty case separately so to be able to check the last character of `aString`.

---

**Addendum**

After @aka.nice's answer it becomes clear that a better version of `#split:` simply reduces to

```
Character >> split: aString
    ^aString splitBy: self asString
```

Moreover, the same idea can be used to implement `#split:` in other classes.