# split function in squeak Smalltalk

Tags: string, split, smalltalk, squeak

I'm currently working on an exercise in squeak-Smalltalk.
I want to split a string that behaves somewhat like split functions in Java or python, but hardly found anything on the internet. Any suggestions please? How can I implement it?

Thank you!

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/a/59436024/4081336

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Squeak(smalltalk) subSrings ignores empty strings at end of string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59435414/squeaksmalltalk-subsrings-ignores-empty-strings-at-end-of-string)

Comment: Unfortunately no, it seems there is no ```split``` or ```splitBy``` message in squeak (unlike Pharo...) so I implemented such a method by myself. thanks a lot anyway for your help!

Comment: So now you need to make an Inbox contribution. Or alternately, which class did you add this to, so somebody else  can contribute this.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Unfortunately no, it seems there is no `split` or `splitBy:` message in squeak (unlike Pharo...) so I implemented such a method by myself.

```
split: aSentence
|count str strArr |
    str := aSentence.
    count := ((aSentence select: [:a | a = $ ])) size.
    strArr := OrderedCollection new.
    [count >= 0]
    whileTrue: [
        strArr add: (str copyFrom: 1 to: (str indexOf: $ ifAbsent: [str size + 1]) - 1).
        str := str copyFrom: ((str indexOf: $ ) + 1) to: (str size).
        count := count - 1.
    ].
^strArr
```

Comment: Just a comment: strArr is a bad name. You don´t need to tell types in Smalltalk, and in this case is misleading because it is not really an Array but an OrderedCollection.I would suggest just "strings" or "substrings", the plural tells you that it is a collection and the name indicates what it contains. I also advice not to trunc the str name, string will be better.

Comment: There's no need to implement this yourself: `SequenceableCollection >> splitBy:` has existed in the Squeak image since at least February, 2010.

Answer (score 1):

I find the protocol browser most helpful for answering this question. Here are some selectors you could give a try:

```
'foo, bar, baz' splitBy: ','. "#('foo' ' bar' ' baz')"
'foo, bar, baz' splitBy: ', '. "#('foo' 'bar' 'baz')"
'foo, bar, baz' findTokens: ', '. "an OrderedCollection('foo' 'bar' 'baz')"
```

But note that while `#splitBy:[Do:]` interprets the parameter as a single separator sequence, `#findTokens:` uses it as a set of single char separators:

```
'foo bar, baz' splitBy: ', '. #('foo bar' ' baz')
'foo bar, baz' findTokens: ', '. an OrderedCollection('foo' 'bar' 'baz')
```

Hope this helps. Enjoy your Squeak!

Answer (score 0):

`SequenceableCollection >> splitBy:` has existed in the Squeak image since at least February, 2010:

```
('1920x1080' splitBy: 'x') = #('1920' '1080')
```